# MySql 8 unable to connect via user

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I have a strange issue. Im using Msql 8 via Docker and Im able to connect via IDE like DataGrip to connect to my db with root user. But only with root. Im trying to establish a connection with a non-root user but It is not working even with all privileges.

I thought I did something wrong when creating a new user, but in my local environment Im able to connect to my db with a non-root user.

This works:

```
mysql --user=test mysql -p
```

Priviligeses:

```
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `test`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN ON *.* TO `test`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION
```

I know there are several similiar question and I tried all of them. But none of them worked or changed something.

Btw. I created my user this way:

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTITY BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost';
```

Comment: "But only with root. Im trying to establish a connection with a non-root user but It is not working even with all privileges. " I assume the root account is also configured to allow connections from localhost and i assume docker is running on the same server as MySQL 8.0 does?

Comment: That is correct. Let me explain this in detail: Im running a Laravel projekt with Nginx and as i said above a mysql database. I put all the environment stuff in my docker-composer file which I start at once on my local machine. Root is allowed to establish connections and this works fine using it on laravel or somewhere else.